# Lost connection to "iPhone 6 (iOS 9.0.2 and Xcode 7)” when running app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode7

Restore the connection to "iPhone 6 (iOS 9.0.2 and Xcode 7)" and run "AppName" again, or if "AppName" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > AppName.

Comment: Only solution is to Re-run your project.

Comment: It happens some times don't worry . Quit Xcode and run again

Comment: Is your app still running on the device after the lost connection error?

Comment: shit happens!! Don't worry! quit xcode or clean and re run!